# In Loki, Can you stake more than the requirement in a service node?

Tags: monero-forks, loki, service-node, staking

Do you get rewarded more if you stake more Loki in a service node?

Comment: In all honesty, if you have questions regarding LOKI, you will be better off asking in their communities. The knowledge on this SE is heavily grounded in Monero.

Comment: yea but its a legitimate question I was curious about. And yes it is on-topic for this stack exchange. See: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23731/are-questions-about-other-cryptonote-coins-on-topic

Comment: I understand it's a legitimate question and fork questions allowed. But to get an answer, you still need knowledgable people from those forks using this SE if you want answers to questions like this. As you will have discovered from your other questions r.e. LOKI, those people are not here.

Comment: https://lokidocs.com/#community-channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot stake more than the maximum amount of 20,000 loki currently as of 2019-OCT-24. The staking requirement gets lowered everyday until it reaches 15,000 loki after 1-2 years. You must stake exactly the required amount of 20,000 loki, if you don't have enough you can open up your staking node as a pool and others can contribute to it to claim a % share of your staking rewards.